# Emulator is terminated android studio AMD processor Windows 11 Home No Hypervisor V option Windows Hypervisor Platfrom available

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation

Hey what I am trying to do is run android emulator but the problem is I cant install HAXM because I am using AMD but there is another problem there is no option in windows features for hypervisor v there is option for Windows hypervisor platform . I tried enabling it but it didnt work and also enabling it messed with my virtual box the parrot OS was not starting but I dont wanna discuss about parrot OS my focus is on Android Studio. I am using windows 11 home maybe that is why there is no hypervisor v option my guess(there us option for windows hypervisor platform). The reason why I am trying to run android studio is because I wanna use react-native CLI with emulator.So I will have to use Tiramisu

CPU Virtualization is enabled